# Cross-form validation issue tapestry

Tags: java, hibernate, authentication, tapestry

I really new in Java....i work some research in java using tool Tapestry  framework...
I have some problem with exception when i calling  @Component "Form"...tapestry throws me exception :

**Embedded component(s) loginForm are defined within component class com.fit.pages.Login (or a super-class of Login), but are not present in the component template (classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml).**

context
eventType

activate

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException

**Embedded component(s) loginForm are defined within component class com.fit.pages.Login (or a super-class of Login), but are not present in the component template (classpath:com/fit/pages/Login.tml).**

trace

```
    **Triggering event 'activate' on Index
    Constructing instance of page class com.fit.pages.Login
    Creating ComponentAssembler for com.fit.pages.Login**
```

my code looks something like this

public class Login {

```
private String userName;

@Property
private String password;

@Inject
@Property
private Users users;

@SessionState
private User user;

@Component(id="loginForm")
private Form loginForm;

@Inject
private Messages messages;

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}



public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}


void onValidate(){
    User authenticatedUser = Security.authenticate(userName, password, users);
    if(authenticatedUser != null){
        user = authenticatedUser;
    }else{
        loginForm.recordError(messages.get("authentication-failed"));
    }
}



@OnEvent
Object onSubmit(){
    System.out.println("form was submited");
    Class nextPage = null;
    User authenticatedUser = Security.authenticate(userName, password, users);
    if(authenticatedUser != null){
        user = authenticatedUser;
        nextPage = Index.class;
    } else {

    nextPage = Registration.class;
    }
    return nextPage;
}
```

and code in login.tml :

Please log in:

```
    <t:form id="loginForm">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <t:label t:for="userName"/>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" t:type="textfield"  t:id="userName" 
                    t:value="userName" t:validate="required"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                <t:label t:for="password"/>:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" t:type="passwordfield"  t:id="password" 
                    t:value="password" t:validate="required"/>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
                </td>
            </tr>               
    </table>    
    </t:form>
```

Comment: Are you using `import org.apache.tapestry.form.Form`?

Comment: Have you tried `<t:form t:id="loginForm">`

Comment: Can I ask what import are you using for Security.authenticate(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
<t:form id="loginForm">
```

with

```
<t:form t:id="loginForm">
```